# TypeScript does not recognize properties when instantiating interface array

Tags: angular, typescript

I have created the following interface that I want to implement in my custom Angular component.

Interface:

```js
export interface Device {
    constructor(
        deviceID: string,
        deviceName: string,
        deviceModel: string,
        manufactureYear: string,
        deviceOS: string
    );
}
```

Custom component

```js
import { Component, OnInit} from "@angular/core";
import { Device } from "src/shared/interfaces/device";

@Component({
    selector: 'device-dashboard',
    templateUrl: './device-dashboard.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./device-dashboard.component.less']
})
export class DeviceDashBoardComponent implements OnInit{
    constructor() {}

    devices: Device[] = [
        {
            deviceID: "12345",
            deviceName: 'name',
            deviceModel: 'model',
            manufactureYear: '2015',
            deviceOS: 'Ubuntu 22.04',
        },
    ];

    ngOnInit(): void {     }
```

Unfortunately, the TS compiler keeps highlighting the first property and shows the following error message when I hover over it.

```bash
Type '{ deviceID: string; deviceName: string; deviceModel: string; manufactureYear: string; deviceOS: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Device'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'deviceID' does not exist in type 'Device'.
```

Comment: remove the constructor method from the interface and just have the properties. constructor methods are for instantiating classes, not typing an object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extend the answer of @about14sheep
The correct Interface would be

```
export interface Device {
    deviceID: string;
    deviceName: string;
    deviceModel: string;
    manufactureYear: string;
    deviceOS: string;
}
```

Edit (thanks to @VLAZ): Your current interface just defines a method called constructor - but no public attributes.

Comment: It defines *a method* called `constructor`. Not "a constructor" as in what you'd need for `new Device()` to be valid code.